# ClassNotFoundException with corresponding bundle loaded at runtime

Tags: dependencies, osgi, classnotfoundexception, bundles

I've lately added a few dependencies to my program and I'm experiencing problems at runtime.
When activating the new feature, I get a ClassNotFoundException. I then whipped up the felixgogo shell and debugged the OSGI environment. I looked at the corresponding bundle and it said the package containing the class should be available.

The exception I got:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/Resource
    at at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server.messagingService.MessagingServiceInstance.doStart(MessagingServiceInstance.java:33)
    at at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server.eventdistributor.AbstractDistributor.start(AbstractDistributor.java:89)
    at at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server.distribution.internal.DistributionServiceInstance.startup(DistributionServiceInstance.java:116)
    at at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server.services.DistributorService.startup(DistributorService.java:63)
    at at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server.remote.facades.DistributorServiceRemoteFacade.startup(DistributorServiceRemoteFacade.java:52)
    at at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.server.impls.ServerStartup.earlyStartup(ServerStartup.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$63.run(Workbench.java:2470)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

The package I therefore need is org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.
Looking up the bundles with the console gave me the following bundle:

```
70  STARTING    org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.10.1.v20140901-1043
```

I then inspected the bundle with command "bundle 70":

```
org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.10.1.v20140901-1043 [70]
  Id=70, Status=STARTING    Data 
  "No registered services."
  No services in use.
  Exported packages
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.namespace; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.namespace.impl; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.namespace.util; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.impl; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.internal; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.util; version="0.0.0"[exported]
...
```

From what I see, the needed package should be available to the OSGI environment, so I'm not quite sure why I'm getting the exception here.

Any suggestions how I could resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Funny enough I found the answer right after posting the question. Although the package was available in the OSGI environment, I have forgotten to add it to the Import-Package list in the MANIFEST file of the bundle that was supposed to use it.
I've simply added

```
Import-Package:
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource
```

to the MANIFEST file, and it worked.